# Difference between String.join and string.join? ReSharper - "Name can be simplified"

Tags: c#, resharper, naming

I've noticed this for a while now and am just curious if there is any advantage or benefit to "simplifying" the name.

Example:

```
var lst = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
string commaLst = String.Join(",", lst);
```

ReSharper then says

> Name can be simplified.

And suggests that I change `String.Join()` to `string.Join()`

Is one way better than the other in terms of performance or anything alike? What's the point of simplifying a name?

Comment: `string` is alias for `String`

Comment: _"What's the point of simplifying a name?"_ You can type `s` faster than `S`.

Comment: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/2016.3/BuiltInTypeReferenceStyle.html by clicking wrench You can always go to `Inspection => Why is Resharper suggesting this`

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary Thanks for the tip. Never knew I could do that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`string` is an alias of `String` in C#

> In C#, string is an alias for the String class in .NET framework. In
>   fact, every C# type has an equivalent in .NET. As another example,
>   short and int in C# map to Int16 and Int32 in .NET. So, technically
>   there is no difference between string and String, but it is common
>   practice to declare a variable using C# keywords.